# TFS 2012 Exception Message: TF246021

Tags: tfs

I'm receiving the following error within TFS

> Exception Message: TF246021: An error occurred while processing your
>   request. Technical information (for administrator): SQL Server Error:
>   2601 (type VersionControlException) Exception Stack Trace:  Server
>   stack trace:     at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation
>   operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Repository5.LabelItem(String
>   workspaceName, String workspaceOwner, VersionControlLabel label,
>   LabelItemSpec[] labelSpecs, LabelChildOption children, Int32
>   maxClientPathLength, Failure[]& failures)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.WebServiceLayer.LabelItem(String
>   workspaceName, String workspaceOwner, VersionControlLabel label,
>   LabelItemSpec[] labelSpecs, LabelChildOption children, Failure[]&
>   failures)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer.CreateLabel(VersionControlLabel
>   label, LabelItemSpec[] itemSpecs, LabelChildOption options, Failure[]&
>   failures)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TfLabel.TfLabelInternal.RunCommand(VersionControlScope
>   versionControlScope, String nonFatalError, VersionControlLabel label,
>   IEnumerable`1 items, LabelChildOption childOption)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message
>   reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed,
>   MessageData& msgData)    at System.Func`6.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.TfLabel.TfLabelInternal.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity`1.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>
> Inner Exception Details:
>
> Exception Message: TF246021: An error occurred while processing your
>   request. Technical information (for administrator): SQL Server Error:
>   2601 (type SoapException)SoapException Details:  Exception
>   Stack Trace:

I've read a previous post within StackOverflow which points at recreating workspaces, I tried that and it doesn't work.

Also I've tried to clean the cache, again without any luck. One thing I noticed when I go and disable 'Label Sources' and run the a build it works. I believe its to do with creating a branch and then deleting some files from a main branch which then gets TFS into a mess. I'm not sure whats the best way to fix this, it'll be difficult to upgrade to a newer version of TFS.

Comment: When will you see this error? Queuing builds? Do you see this error before? Do you change anything to TFS recently? How did you clean the cache?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your TFS 2012 has been upgraded to the latest edition Update 4.
2. Make sure the build server has the same edition with TFS Application Tier.
3. Make sure both client cache and server cache are cleaned. Client cache: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache`. Server cache: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Web Access\Cache_v11.0`
4. Check Event log in Event Viewer to see whether there is something helpful.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll check those items you've suggested and mark appropriately. Thanks

Comment: Did this issue occur when queue builds? Did you see this error before?

Comment: The build was in progress and stopped within 8 seconds of every build for the Main branch, nothing for the other branches.

Comment: This issue occurs for all Main branches in your TFS? Have you checked the Event Log? Anything helpful? If you get one of the main branch on your build machine and queue a build manually, can you get it build?

Comment: It's only a certain branch it's affecting, everything builds locally fine. We're in discussions with the team to updrage to update 4 at the moment, will let you know how we get along. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: The management decided to create a new branch leaving the old one in tact, it was due to resourcing issues. Thanks for your help, if they ever decide to get it working I'll update the answer. Thanks